# CSS jQuery Flip Animation

Tags: jquery, css

When i mouseover over any box it will be flip, And when i click View Collection, It will open flexslider. But as long as i remove mouse over that box, the flip come back to previous position.

I just want to flip box not show behind the flexslider box. link is below:
http://luutaa.co.in/TMcollection/

Please help me how any condition, the flip box not show behind flexslider box.

Comment: Check this link http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/ I guess this is the easiest way to get your job done!

Answer (score 0):

Here a lot of them google before asking! 
http://www.jquery4u.com/animation/10-jquery-flip-effect-plugins/